# Alert the user when exceeding 25 characters in a text view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm new to Objective-C. I have created a textview in code, that limits its text to 25 characters. When the user wants to add more than 25 characters in the textview it shows an alert view... Now the problem is, when I click the done button it again shows the alert view. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but throwing up an alert dialog in this situation sounds really annoying.

Comment: i m throwing alert View to tell d user not to enter more than 25 characters

Comment: Yeah, that's a really annoying way to tell the user not to enter more than 25 characters. The friendlier approach would be to give the field a label explaining the 25 character limit, and then when the user reaches 25 characters, just give an NSBeep() and don't accept the input. The user will figure it out and his workflow won't be interrupted.

Comment: @Chuck: a beep being friendlier than an alert? dont think so... a beep is a 'wordless alert'.  (as alerts do beep) eww.

Comment: I kind of like the strategy most Twitter clients use, to allow the user to enter more than n characters, but not 'submit' the data if it's over the limit. A counter somewhere tells you how many characters you've typed, and if you're over the limit. This way you can get your thoughts out of your head and into the text field, and revise it until you have a valid entry.

Comment: @kent: 100% YES. Pretty much anything short of starting a fire is friendlier than a modal dialog. The difference between a beep and an alert is that people don't have to click on a beep to make it go away before they can start working again. People hate having their workflow needlessly interrupted. Beeping when the user tries to do input and it isn't allowed is the standard behavior on the Mac. A modal dialog should only be displayed when something really urgent has happened or user input is required to proceed.

Comment: @chuck: beeping at an ipod touch user is evil. best to just take SO's example: as I type this I see that I have 488 characters left. and I'm willing to bet that when I reach the limit it doesn't beep:...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................nope. the character count turned red. but no beeps...

Comment: @kent: Sure. Different platform, different conventions. It's also good to have a close widget and menus in a Cocoa app, but not on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, an alert is perhaps the most primitive, non-elegant, un-friendly form of user interaction a programmer can turn to. you should turn to alerts as an absolute last resort.

though the question is a bit vague, it sounds to me as though your logic is this

```
while(strlen(textview) > 25)
{
 // show alert
}
```

so of course, when you show the alert, you need to truncate the length of the string to be less than 25, no?  else you have a really boring game called 'click away the never ending alert!'

a more elegant solution would be to display the number of characters entered, and when it's getting close to the limit (say, over 20) then to make said display red, and instead of showing an alert to simply disallow further input after the 25th character (EXCEPTING OF COURSE THE BACKSPACE and DELETE!)

Comment: cud you tell me code of limit the input after 25th character except backspace  delete

Answer (score 2):

I think I have to agree to all previous users that this type of warning could be quite annoying for the user. Even if you change your way to something less obtrusive you still need to validate the input.

I think the correct way would be to use the Data Formatting features of Cocoa. You can find more information about it at: [isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000204-BABBGCHC).

As you can read there, you can return `NO`, and the last inserted char will not be appended. With the control delegate control:didFailToValidatePartialString:errorDescription: it's even possible to use the default behaviour of Mac OS for such cases, which might change in the future.